# Laptop battery not working after changing HDD to SSD

Tags: laptop, ssd, hardware-failure, battery

I have an Asus X542UA Laptop which I opened up and changed the HDD to an SSD. After doing so I checked if everything connected and seems fine. The battery charging lights went on when I plugged it, I turned on the lapton and everything seemed to work fine. The battery indicator showed 99% charging, but when I unplugged the laptop from the charger it's being turned off (sometimes not immediately). It seemed to me rather odd, and I'm quite scared to open the laptop again since it has FFC cables which I need to disconnect to open it up. I have used a different operating system for the new SSD, am I missing an essential program which controls the battery? Is it possible that the new SSD draws more power than the battery can manage? Or have I connected the battery wrong? I don't want to open the laptop up without any lead for what might cause the problem. I can just put the old HDD and see if it works... But then I bought a new SSD for nothing.

Comment: changed the HDD to an SSD.  <-- Update the BIOS and the Power Management driver.  SSDs do not harm batteries.

Comment: Ok, I will try to update the bios, I have tried to update the battery driver though. Didn't seem to make it work.

Comment: Try also the Power driver (different on my laptop than battery driver).

Comment: Run hardware diagnostics from the UEFI boot page or within the UEFI firmware settings, and you may need to [re-open](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0pCc47KGaY) the laptop since there's no access to the battery through the bottom case. There are only 4 possible causes: battery & motherboard power terminals need to be cleaned with a cotton swab and isopropyl alcohol _(preferably a 90% solution)_, battery has degraded _(laptop batteries have a finite lifetime of ~300 charge cycles)_, battery charger has a hardware failure, or ASUS may use a communication center pin on the DC jack that's failed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tend to agree with John's answer though. Seems like changing the ssd to an image which is not the HDD one was a mistake which is likely to cause the problems in my opinion. If I can't solve this easily then I'll try to image the HDD on the SSD and then see how it goes.